# Base Class Not Defined and Other Errors in Pong clone (C++)

Tags: c++, clone, pong

Trying to get back into the swing of things with C++ development, so I've been trying to build a simple 'Pong' clone in C++, using MS Visual Studios 2010. At this point I'm trying to just get the game screen with a single, stationary paddle/racket to display, but am running into a series of errors. I've checked other similar posts and tried their techniques for resolving these issues, but to no avail. I've been building this in accordance with a series of tutorials over at 'GamesFromScratch.Com', but no one else there seemed to have any of the issues I'm facing, so I've decided to post about them over here. Thanks in advance for any help rendered.

Here is my failed build output:

VisibleGameObject.cpp

1>c:\documents and settings\lguser\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\puck\puck\playerracket.h(7): error C2504: 'VisibleGameObject' : base class undefined

1>  PlayerRacket.cpp

1>c:\documents and settings\lguser\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\puck\puck\game.h(24): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '_player1'

1>c:\documents and settings\lguser\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\puck\puck\game.h(24): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

1>c:\documents and settings\lguser\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\puck\puck\game.h(24): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

1>c:\documents and settings\lguser\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\puck\puck\game.h(24): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

And here are the files referenced in the error readout:

PlayerRacket.h:

http://pastebin.com/y1v1nJ8s

Game.h:

http://pastebin.com/CXNPbtiq

See y'all on the flipside,

Kian

Comment: Show us `VisibleGameObject.h`

Comment: VisibleGameObject.h: http://pastebin.com/mK9Ny9aS

Answer (score 1):

You probably have cyclic includes: `VisibleGameObject.h` includes `Game.h` which includes `PlayerRacket.h` which includes `VisibleGameObject.h`. You have to somehow avoid including `Game.h` from `VisibleGameObject.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't show the content of VisibleGameObject.h so I can only guess that it does not contain the `VisibleGameObject` class (the first error). Following errors are implied by the first one.

Comment: VisibleGameObject.h: pastebin.com/mK9Ny9aS